# dataset .readxml with URLs containg ampersands in elements

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I am reading an xml file into a dataset using he dataset.readxml method, and I have come across a problem when an element contains a specific form of URL.  The compiler throws this exception:

An error occurred while parsing EntityName.

The problem occours in the URL when an ampersand is detected after the equals sign.

http://somewebsite.net/something?=a&b=

If i change the ampersand to its hex code %26, or any other character for that matter, the string will be read in, but it will not be a valid URL until i replace the hex with an ameprsand, which would beone solution.

Another way I was thinking of using a the CDATA[] tag, but from my understanding, i would have to read the xml file get any CDATA[] values first then use the dataset.readxml to fill the dataset.

Does anybody know why it is causing problems, and think of any other solutions?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ampersand in XML content should be written "& a m p ;" (without the spaces), whether it appears in a URL or anywhere else. When an application tries to process the XML, the XML parser will convert this back to an ampersand, so the URI will work correctly.

Comment: OK yeah i understand, you just cant have ampersands in a xml document without escaping them first. thanks